# Replace text in PDF using Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, pdf

I am looking for a way to replace text in an PDF document in my Mac Application. But the problem is that I don't know how. I am thinking of converting the PDF to an HTML file, so I can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` and then converting it back to an PDF, but I can not find out how.

I also tried to replace the text using `CGPDFDocumentRef` but I couldn't find a valide method.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks, David

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to replace text in PDF using CGPDF* API. PDF -> HTML -> PDF will not work because the double conversion will loose content (PDF and HTML formats are not quite compatible). 
The only solution is to find a 3rd party toolkit that supports this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, the source file is a .pages document, may I be able to replace the text here and then convert it into a PDF document?

Comment: @DavidG.: uh... "Sure, why not?" ... but I bet you mean *without using Pages*.